# Asymptotic runtime for an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I've decided to try and do a problem about analyzing the worst possible runtime of an algorithm and to gain some practice.
Since I'm a beginner I only need help in expressing my answer in a right way.
I came accros this problem in a book that uses the following algorithm:

Input: A set of n points (x1, y1), . . . , (xn, yn) with n ≥ 2.
Output: The squared distance of a closest pair of points.
ClosePoints

```
1. if n = 2 then return (x1 − x2)^2 + (y1 − y2)^2
2. else
3. d ← 0
4. for i ← 1 to n − 1 do
5.   for j ← i + 1 to n do
6.     t ← (xi − xj)^2 + (yi − yj)^2
7.     if t < d then
8.       d ← t
9. return d
```

My question is how can I offer a good proof that  T(n) = O(n^2),T(n) = Ω(n^2) and T (n) = Θ(n^2)?,where T(n) represents the worst possible runtime.
I know that we say that f is O(g), 
if and only if there is an n0 ∈ N and c > 0 in R such that for all
n ≥ n0 we have
f(n) ≤ cg(n).
And also we say that f is Ω(g) if there is an
n0 ∈ N and c > 0 in R such that for all n ≥ n0 we have
f(n) ≥ cg(n).

Now I know that the algoritm is doing c * n(n - 1) iterations, yielding T(n)=c*n^2 - c*n.
The first 3 lines are executed O(1) times line 4 loops for  n - 1  iterations which is O(n) . Line 5 loops for  n - i  iterations which is also  O(n) .Does each line of the inner loop's content
(lines 6-7) takes (n-1)(n-i) or just O(1)?and why?The only variation is how many times 8.(d ← t) is performed but it must be lower than or equal to O(n^2).

So,how should I write a good  and complete proof that T(n) = O(n^2),T(n) = Ω(n^2) and T (n) = Θ(n^2)?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of times `t` changes its value. Since changing `t` is the innermost operation performed, finding how many times that happens will allow you to find the complexity of the entire algorithm.

```
i = 1 => j runs n - 1 times (t changes value n - 1 times)
i = 2 => j runs n - 2 times
...
i = n - 1 => j runs 1 time
```

So the number of times `t` changes is `1 + 2 + ... + n - 1`. This sum is equal `n(n - 1) / 2`. This is dominated by `0.5 * n^2`.

Now just find appropriate constants and you can prove that this is `Ω(n^2), O(n^2), Θ(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

`T(n)=c*n^2 - c*n` approaches `c*n^2` for large `n`, which is the definition of `O(n^2)`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I'm interested in some advice on writting a complete proof?

Comment: sorry but I have to disagree with you here we are only guaranteed an upper bound of cf(n) for example, for some constant c > 0.

Comment: @Patrick88: Actually you have both bounds here. Just take closer look at omega definition. c1*n^2<=c*n^2-c*n => c1<=c-c/n; and obviously starting from some n0 for your c you can get c1. QED

Answer (score 0):

if you observe the two `for` loops, each `for` loop gives an O(n) because each loop is incrementing/decrementing in a linear fashion. hence, two loops combined roughly give a O(n^2) complexity. the whole point of big-oh is to find the dominating term- coeffecients do not matter. i would strongly recommend formatting your pseudocode in a proper manner in which it is not ambiguous. in any case, the if and else loops do no affect the complexity of the algorithm.

lets observe the various definitions:

> **Big-Oh**
>
> • f(n) is O(g(n)) if f(n) is
>   asymptotically “less than or equal” to
>   g(n)
>
> **Big-Omega**
>
> • f(n) is Ω(g(n)) if f(n) is
>   asymptotically “greater than or equal”
>   to g(n)
>
> **Big-Theta**
>
> • f(n) is Θ(g(n)) if f(n) is
>   asymptotically “equal” to g(n)

so all you need are to find constraints which satisfy the answer.